# How to select last element within a set of containers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several containers on my page that have a trailing <br> I want to remove. The containers are in the same class, but I am having trouble with the ":last" selector (if that is what I should be using).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="side-section">
    <p>Something 1</p>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="side-section">
    <p>Something 2</p>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="side-section">
    <p>Something 3 <br> Test 3</p>
    <br>
</div>
```

How do I remove the last <br> from .side-section containers? I tried the below but it did not work:

```
$(".side-section br").filter(":last").remove();
$(".side-section").filter("br:last").remove();
```

Comment: curious, why not just remove the `<br />`'s server side from html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(".side-section > br:last-child").remove();
```

the `>` selector is there to make sure you dont remove `<br>` tags inside the `<p>` tag

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".side-section > br:last-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".side-section br:last").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" });
```